# Windows 10 scheduled task not running

Tags: windows, windows-10, scheduled-tasks

I have a very simple bat file which does a MysqlDump.
When I manually execute the bat file, it works. When I click "execute" in my scheduled taks, it works. But the scheduled task itself, doesn't run when it should run (timer expires).

I've setup a scheduled task to run every 5 minutes. In the scheduled taks manager I can see "next time to execute" "16:55". But when it is 16:55 the text updates to "next time to execute" "17:00". But in the "previous time executed" nothing changes. It still shows the time I manually have executed the task.

So, the weird thing is, when I click "execute" for the task, it runs. But when the time expires and it should run by itself, nothing happend.

I've enabled the history for the task. But even there nothing happens.

Can you help?

Comment: What credentials is it expected to run with? Might be permissions issue. Check event log and see if there's some info in there.

Comment: Nothing in there. It is running under Admin privileges.

Comment: I've seen this before.  In your case, you have a  task time to execute at 16:55.  It is supposed to run again at 17:00 but doesn't.  The reason is, perhaps you've edited the properties of the task after you first saved it.  You need to re-trigger the task (and not by simply disabling and then re-enabling, which didn't work in my just completed test).  To fully re-trigger, look at the time right now, and then configure the task to start 3 minutes from now, and then set it to repeat every 5 minutes.  That should work.